# Can a neural net (MLP) approximate a GLM?

Tags: machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, neural-networks

I know the activation function (logistic) is linear around 0.

Does this then imply a neural net should be able to approximate a GLM given the right bias and weights?

I am currently playing in R with a simple model `y~x1`.

The GLM performs well out of sample, yet the nnet with 1 hidden variable does poorly.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing an adequate number of hidden variables to do decent approximation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the same reasoning, you could say a 2nd degree polynomial function can approximate a linear function. It is true, but the polynomial model is more complex.

This means that you will need more data to fit it correctly and it will have a stronger tendency to overfit. So, if the true model is a line and you fit/evaluate a linear model versus a 2nd degree polynomial model, the linear model will do likely better for a given amount of data.

Comment: I would agree that if you want a specific GLM, you should use that and skip the neural network. However, I think your answer undersells their ability a bit. It's true that quadratic model like $ax^2 + bx +c$ can approximate $bx+c$, but a line rarely approximates a quadratic function well. However, given enough data and hidden units, a MLP can approximate whatever you want: $ax^2+bx+c$, $a+sin(2*\pi*x)$, $e^{-ax}$, and so on.

Comment: @MattKrause I did not mean to suggest that one should not use complex models. They just need more data in order to generalize well. So usually if you do not have a good reason to use a complex model, it would be better to keep the model as simple as possible (which is essentially Occam's razor).

Answer (score 5):

A multilayer feed-forward network is a universal function approximator, so yes, it can approximate a GLM (or any other function you happen to dream up). The key word there, however, is "approximator" and the quality of the approximation depends on the number of hidden units, the network's training, etc.

The classic paper on this is [Cybenko (1989)](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~gvc/Cybenko_MCSS.pdf), who showed that it was true for sigmoidal activation functions. This was followed up by [Hornik (1991)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/089360809190009T), who showed the multilayer architecture, not the activation function per se, was the key.